# $http.get(url) not working

Tags: angularjs, json, http

I am working on $http to fetch details from another file using angular js.

```
<body>
  <h2>AngularJS</h2>
  <div ng-app = "" ng-controller = "sController">

     <table>
        <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Roll No</th>
           <th>Percentage</th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat = "student in students">
           <td>{{ student.Name }}</td>
           <td>{{ student.RollNo }}</td>
           <td>{{ student.Percentage }}</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
  </div>

<script>
     function studentController($scope,$http) {
        var url = "C:\\Users\\Test\\Desktop\\data.txt";

        $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
        alert('success');
           $scope.students = response;
        }).error(function (response) {
    alert("error");

    return status;
    });
    }
</script>
```

data.txt file contains the student details in json format .

```
[{"Name" : "Smith","RollNo" : 11,"Percentage" : "80%"}]
```

The control doesn't go inside success. Am i missing something? Also i am not getting anything inside response. Please help.

Comment: have you registered your controller? (`angular.module(moduleName).controller...`

Comment: Create a Module for angular and refer the app name, also register the controller with the App Name

Answer (score 1):

It's an http request and the file should be hosted somewhere, and always its better to have json as a json extension file.

There are few issues with your code ,

(i) I don't see a Module name

(ii)You have defined your controller as `sController` and using it as `studentController`

Check this sample

```
app.controller("MyController", ["$scope","$http",
    function($scope, $http) {
             $http.get('test.json').then(function (response){
                $scope.students = response.data;
                console.log(response.data);
        });

}]);
```

Here is the working [`sample`](https://plnkr.co/edit/T3WEVeqQpRAojCt5ucPJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code, where I have made to read the content directly from text to make it easy to understand, you can add the "http" to read the content from the URL context.

This AngularJS Code have the proper Module and controller registered to module part, which I have tested and attached the screen shot below.

Please, let me know, if you have any queries.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html ng-app="MyApp">
         <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
          <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
          <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/angular.js" 
             data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
          <script>
             var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
             
             
             
             app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
               $scope.name = "World";
             
               var text = 
             
             '[{"Name" : "Smith","RollNo" : 111,"Percentage" : "80%"}]';
             
               var obj = JSON.parse
             
             (text);
             
               $scope.students = obj;
             
             });
          </script>
       </head>
           <body ng-
              controller="MainCtrl">
                  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
              <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
             <table>
                <tr>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Roll No</th>
                   <th>Percentage</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
                   <td>{{ student.Name }}</td>
                   <td>{{ student.RollNo }}</td>
                   <td>{{ student.Percentage }}</td>
                </tr>
             </table>
          </div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Output of Code:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please correct the controller name in function.Use `sController` instead of `studentController` and as you are making `$http` request so it will find the file which is hosted in some url either `http://localhost` or any other `domain`.

**Html :**

```
<div ng-app = "MyApp" ng-controller = "sController">
```

**Script :**

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("MyApp",[]);
    app.controller("sController",function ($scope,$http) {
        var url = "http://www.example.com/data.txt";

        $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
        alert('success');
           $scope.students = response;
        }).error(function (response) {
    alert("error");

    return status;
    });
    });
</script>
```